# Input triangle sides's length and output triangle type. Doesn't work

Tags: python

so, this is my code and python doesn't seem to run the lines in bold. Basically, it's a code where the user inputs the three lengths of the three triangle sides and it outputs the type of the triangle (equilateral, isosceles, scalene( that isn't working. Help me please) or right).

```
    x= input (" Length of side 1 =  ")
    y= input ("Length of side 2 =  ")
    z= input ("Length of side 3 = ")

    x= float (x)
    y= float (y)
    z= float (z)

    flag=0

    if x==y==z:
      print ("This is an equilateral triangle")
    flag=1

    if x>y and x>z and (x**2) == ((z**2) + (y**2)):
      print ("This is a right triangle")
    flag=1

    if z>y and z>x and (z**2) ==((x**2) + (y**2)):
     print ("This is a right triangle")
    flag=1

    if y>z and y>x and (y**2) == ((z**2) + (x**2)):
     print ("This is a right triangle")
    flag=1

    **if x!=z!=y and flag==0:
     print("This triangle is scalene")**

    if x==z and x!= y:
     print ("This triangle is isosceles")

    if x==y and x!= z:
     print ("This triangle is isosceles")

    if z==y and z!= x:
     print ("This triangle is isosceles")
```

Comment: `(x!=z!=y)` is shorthand form of `(x != z and z != y)`. This could evaluate to `True` even if `y == x`. If you want to test if all three are not equal you need `x != y != z != x`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor improvements to help you learn:

```
def identify_triangle(x, y, z):
    def tri_print(tri_type):
        print("This is an {} triangle".format(tri_type))

    if all([x==y, x==z]):
        triangle_type = "equilateral"

    elif any([
        all([x>y, x>z, (x**2)==((z**2)+(y**2))]),
        all([z>y, z>x, (z**2)==((x**2)+(y**2))]),
        all([y>z, y>x, (y**2)==((z**2)+(x**2))]),
        ]):
        triangle_type = "right"

    elif all([x!=z, z!=y, x!=y]):
        triangle_type = "scalene"

    elif any([
        all([x==z, x!=y]),
        all([x==y, x!=z]),
        all([z==y, z!=x]),
    ]):
        triangle_type = "isosceles"
    else:
        triangle_type = "Unknown"

    tri_print(triangle_type)
    return triangle_type

x= float(input("Length of side 1 = "))
y= float(input("Length of side 2 = "))
z= float(input("Length of side 3 = "))
print()
identify_triangle(x, y, z)
```